# python: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'long' objects

Tags: python

I'm trying to set up a choice field in django, but I don't think this is a django issue. The choices field takes an iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) of 2-tuples to use as choices for this field.

Here's my code:

```
self.fields['question_' + question.id] = forms.ChoiceField(
                label=question.label,
                help_text=question.description,
                required=question.answer_set.required,
                choices=[("fe", "a feat"), ("faaa", "sfwerwer")])
```

for some reason, i always get the following error:

```
TypeError - cannot concatenate 'str' and 'long' objects
```

The last line is always highlighted.

I'm not trying to concatenate anything. Almost regardless of what I change the list to for the 'choices' parameter, I get this error.

What's going on?

Comment: Note that "the last line is highlighted" because it's pointing to the whole multi-line statement in which the error is located.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Most likely it's highlighting the last line only because you split the statement over multiple lines.

The fix for the *actual* problem will most likely be changing

```
self.fields['question_' + question.id]
```

to

```
self.fields['question_' + str(question.id)]
```

As you can quickly test in a Python interpreter, adding a string and a number together doesn't work:

```
>>> 'hi' + 6

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    'hi' + 6
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
>>> 'hi' + str(6)
'hi6'
```

Answer (score 6):

`'question_'` is a string, `question.id` is a long. You can not concatenate two things of different types, you will have to convert the long to a string using `str(question.id)`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably `question.id` is an integer. Try

```
self.fields['question_' + str(question.id)] = ...
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
self.fields['question_' + question.id]
```

That looks like the problem. Try

```
"question_%f"%question.id
```

or

```
"question_"+ str(question.id)
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a problem with doing too many things in one line - the error messages become slightly less helpful. Had you written it as below the problem would be much easier to find

```
question_id = 'question_' + question.id
self.fields[question_id] = forms.ChoiceField(
                label=question.label,
                help_text=question.description,
                required=question.answer_set.required,
                choices=[("fe", "a feat"), ("faaa", "sfwerwer")])
```