# Python TypeError cannot concatenate str and 'xxxxx' objects

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting the following results when I try to 'get' my remote files. I can print and I know the files are there. Do I need to build the files into a list?

```
file_list_attr = sftp.listdir_attr()
for pfile in file_list_attr:
    if DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(pfile.st_mtime) > yesterday:
       # print pfile
       localfile = path + "\\" + pfile
       sftp.get(pfile,localfile) 



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\tyoffe\Desktop\FTP", line 41, in <module>
localfile = path + "\\" + pfile
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'SFTPAttributes' objects
```

Comment: This question is essentially the same as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532873/python-cannot-concatenate-str-and-long-objects so you might find it useful to read the answers to that also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `.filename` property instead, see the [`SFTPAttributes` documentation](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SFTPAttributes-class.html):

```
file_list_attr = sftp.listdir_attr()
for pfile in file_list_attr:
    if DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(pfile.st_mtime) > yesterday:
       # print pfile
       localfile = path + "\\" + pfile.filename
       sftp.get(pfile,localfile)
```

Comment: Ahh ... then in that case, I'll delete my comment.  Seems like I'm having an off day ... Maybe it's time to spend a little time trying to get my other code to compile :)

Answer (score 0):

The key is in the last line:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'SFTPAttributes' objects
```

The error is telling you that the SFTPAttributes object is not a string, and that a string can only be concatenated with a string. I'm not sure how to typecast SFTPAttributes to a string, things you can try are:

```
str(pfile)
```

or something like pfile.tostring()

What works best will usually depend on the details of the object itself.

Comment: This did not work either. Looks like I have to dig a bit deeper in paramiko