# Python on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, rfid

I am trying to code a RFID access system that utilizes an actuator to turn on and off. I followed a simple tutorial that can be found [here](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/).

I completed the tutorial fully and now have encountered problems:

1. I noticed when following the tutorial, the "python" we were coding was different from actual Python... for example, we don't do the curly brackets to end anything. Is there a way I can program and have access to my RFID module with the normal "Python" that I learned?
2. I am having issues finding the syntax's attached to SimpleMFRC522, because from what I read, it is a simplified way to interact with the RFID reader. So shouldn't there be certain syntax/functions attached to it?
3. When running a simple program that reads a tags ID and TEXT associated with the tag, I come across errors that usually wouldn't be an error on the normal python, for example...

   [Python Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NxdW.png)

   After running that code (labeled 'Python Code'), I come across...

   [Actual Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnzgM.png)

I am extremely confused and need guidance or referral to anything I could possibly learn to help me finish this project. All or any help is appreciated and seriously considered.

Comment: Those look like normal python errors to me

Comment: There are no "curly brackets" on the linked tutorial

Comment: Don't post code as images. Or errors. Format as text please.

Comment: The error you see is completely expected from the code you posted. It's just bad code. What is the actual question?

Comment: Thank you for all your inputs, I will take all of it into consideration next time and will come back with better questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar issue to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3532890/7253829) post.

You cannot concatenate a string and an integer so you must pull the id out of the object then typecast it to a string:

*unsure what the 'id' name is within the object but let's assume it's 'id'*

```
... (code above)

try:
    print('Place your tag to be read.')
    id_obj, text = reader.read()
    print('Your ID is ' + str(id_obj.id))
    print('Your text is ' + text)

... (code below)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

I apologize for such a newby, poorly-written question. My extreme confusion and lack of knowledge on these topics lead to this.

Comment: no worries but, as the other comments suggest, in the future it would help if you provide the raw code in a format that people can easily manipulate